# Align vertical center CSS clock in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Facing a problem in this bootstrap code.

1. section "hero"  ( background gradient )
2. container

   - CSS & JS clock
   - text
3. waves

I want the container to be aligned vertically centered to the xl-lg-md-sm-col screen resolutions with equal padding or margin from top & bottom.

when ever i try adjusting the padding wave at the bottom also moves along.

> **Need a output like this https://ibb.co/7x3NF2s**

here is the code-pen
https://codepen.io/haribabu-manoharan/pen/xxEdWez

```js
// java scrtipt for clock


const deg = 6;
const hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
const mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
const sc = document.querySelector('#sc');

setInterval(() => {

    let day = new Date();
    let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
    let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
    let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

    hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
    mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
    sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;

})



// java scrtipt for clock
```

```css
#hero {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 260px 0 0 0;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/*EDITED NERAM*/
#hero:before {
    content: "";
    /*background: rgba(2, 5, 161, 0.91);*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(111.37738709038058deg, rgba(43, 45, 78, 1) 1.557291666666667%, rgba(225, 20, 139, 1) 101.34895833333333%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    /*added*/
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#hero h1 {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#hero h1 span {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1acc8d;
}

#hero h2 {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 27px;
}

#hero .btn-get-started {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    background: #1acc8d;
}

#hero .btn-get-started:hover {
    background: #17b57d;
}

#hero .animated {
    animation: up-down 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate-reverse both;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    #hero {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    #hero {
        padding-top: 260px;
    }

    #hero .animated {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        animation: none;
    }

    #hero .hero-img {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #hero .hero-img img {
        max-width: 45%;
    }

    #hero h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #hero h2 {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
    #hero .hero-img img {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes up-down {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@keyframes up-down {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

.hero-waves {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    top: -29px;
}


@media (max-width:767px) {
    #hero {
        padding-top: 4px;
    
    }
}

.wave1 use {
    -webkit-animation: move-forever1 10s linear infinite;
    animation: move-forever1 10s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave2 use {
    -webkit-animation: move-forever2 8s linear infinite;
    animation: move-forever2 8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}

.wave3 use {
    -webkit-animation: move-forever3 6s linear infinite;
    animation: move-forever3 6s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever1 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(85px, 0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
    }
}

@keyframes move-forever1 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(85px, 0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever2 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(85px, 0%);
    }
}

@keyframes move-forever2 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(85px, 0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-forever3 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(85px, 0%);
    }
}

@keyframes move-forever3 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(85px, 0%);
    }
}

/** clock css **/

.clock {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(../img/clock.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 -25px +25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        inset 0 -25px +25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
        inset 0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.clock:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
    position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
    width: 260px;
    height: 150px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
    width: 250px;
    height: 190px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
    width: 330px;
    height: 205px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*align-items: center;*/
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #ff105e;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.mn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 11;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.sc:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 130px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 12;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="hero">
      <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
           
            <div class="row pt-lg-n5 mt-col-5 pt-col-5 mt-sm-5 pt-sm-5 mt-md-0 pt-md-0 d-flex align-self-center">

                <div class="justify-content-sm-center col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 offset-xl-1 col-xl-4 order-1 d-flex align-items-center hero-img" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="300">

                    <!-- HTML for clock -->

                    <div class="clock">
                        <div class="hour">
                            <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="min">
                            <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sec">
                            <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- End HTML for clock -->

                </div>
                
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-lg-0 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 order-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div data-aos="zoom-out">
                        <h1>Why neram Classes for <span>NATA Coaching ?</span></h1><br>
                        <h2>We are team of talanted practising architects from IITs & NITs started this for betterment of this Architecture profession </h2>
                        <div class="text-center text-lg-left">
                            <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Get Started</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <svg class="hero-waves" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 24 150 28 " preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <defs>
                <path id="wave-path" d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z">
            </defs>
            <g class="wave1">
                <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="1" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .1)">
            </g>
            <g class="wave2">
                <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="-2" fill="rgba(255,255,255, .2)">
            </g>
            <g class="wave3">
                <use xlink:href="#wave-path" x="50" y="7" fill="#fff">
            </g>
        </svg>

    </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so necessary? - https://ibb.co/x83Hdj3

Comment: kindly try changing in code pen where i have the container and also check weather it is responsive in all screens

Comment: need a output like this.https://ibb.co/7x3NF2s